# Why tornado removed database after v3.0

Tags: python, mysql, database

what is the reason that database module is removed? Just because the database module is not async?

Any one could give me the detail and what is the best way of using python to connect  mysql?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the module is frozen and unmaintained.

> The tornado.database module has been removed. It is now available as a separate package, [torndb](https://github.com/bdarnell/torndb)

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/releases/v3.0.0.html#backwards-incompatible-changes

> Torndb is a simple wrapper around MySQLdb that originally appeared in
>   Tornado (http://www.tornadoweb.org). It is being moved into a separate
>   package for Tornado 3.0.
>
> This package is not actively maintained, and since it exists primarily
>   for backwards compatibility with the module provided in Tornado prior
>   to version 3.0, I do not intend to make major changes or merge pull
>   requests that do so. You are welcome to create a fork, but pull
>   requests are unlikely to get merged into this repo.